# Why shouldn't I include <bits/sigaction.h>, and how do I ignore the error when I do so?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, sigaction

I'm currently trying to instrument part of the SPEC OMP 2012 benchmark suite using the Score-P profiling tool, and I'm getting an error. Specifically:

```
/XXX/imagick/src/magick_magick.c: In function ‘SetMagickSignalHandler’:
/XXX/imagick/src/magick_magick.c:1137:20: error: storage size of ‘action’ isn’t known
    struct sigaction action, previous_action;
```

Based on information I found [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=6408), the problem is that when I compile with `-std=c99` (using `gcc 6.2.1`), the compiler doesn't recognize `sigaction` as it's not in the C99 spec.

Interestingly, when I compile *without* Score-P, I don't have this problem at all. But that's another story.

All of that being said, I still need to instrument this program. I don't care about portability either. And I'm aware of the fact that you should not directly include `<bits/sigaction.h>`. With that in mind, I'd still like to know:

1. How do I ignore the `#error` that gets thrown as soon as I try to compile>
2. Why does this error exist?

Comment: Why don't you simply compile without `-std=c99` then?

Comment: @melpomene: ...you know how sometimes the answer is really obvious, and you don't see it until someone smacks you across the face? Yeah, I'll do that lol. Thanks! Would still appreciate an answer to the question for my own curiosity though :)

Comment: I think the answers are 1) you don't and 2) because you're not supposed to directly include `<bits/sigaction.h>`. :-)

Comment: I've had a look at [the `sigaction` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rt_sigaction.2.html) and it seems you can `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1` before including `<signal.h>` to get the declaration even in C99 mode. Alternatively you can use `-std=gnu99` to get C99 mode + all GNU extensions.

Comment: @melpomene: I didn't see that on the man page -- thanks!! WRT to (2), surely there's a better reason than that... is it a portability issue? Are they using weird macros or something? Or is it just a matter of they want to hide the implementation because it's good software engineering practice?